# Creating model in rails does not create a corresponding table in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

Havent come across this before, i am generating a model in rails

```
rails g model Rating ratings:integer
```

at this point no migration file is being generated

I then run

```
 rake db:migrate
```

Nothing happens at this point and the model doesn’t get written a table even though myapp_development and myapp_test exists

So i checked mysql, logged in with just

```
mysql
```

and it logged straight in, neither database existed in there, I then logged in again but this time with this command

```
mysql -u root
```

and in here my databases exist. Does anyone know what is going on here and how do i get my models to create a corresponding table?

database.yml

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: recipes_development
pool: 5
username: root
password:
```

Thanks

Comment: When you just type mysql, this will use your current user to login. However if you use -u root, it will use the root user (like in your database.yml).

Comment: so this has nothing to do with my issue?

Comment: As long as Rails can connect to the database, I don't think that this is related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

your generator  looks ok.
1.
it is for me (Rails 3.2):

```
$ rails g model Rating ratings:integer
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20130218203713_create_ratings.rb
      create    app/models/rating.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/unit/rating_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/ratings.yml
$ cat db/migrate/20130218203713_create_ratings.rb
class CreateRatings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ratings do |t|
      t.integer :ratings

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

try rake db:migrate --trace

UPD
2. and you can check schema_migrations table in DB.

Comment: i dont get a migration file being generated, all i get is invoke active_record and create app/models/rating.rb

Comment: ive made some comments on the below answer, does this shed any light on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

Check the timestamps on your migration file and your `db/schema.rb` file. If you've been working on different branches of git recently, you could have problems with the timestamps.

If this is the case, try deleting your `schema.rb` file, then re-running `rake db:migrate`

Comment: im only using master branch at moment and havent actually created a new branch for this app yet

Comment: Interesting... Can you post the contents of the generated migration file?

Comment: thats the thing no migration file being generated

Comment: i tried rake db:reset and then rake db:migrate but in the reset i got this at the end assume_migrated_upto_version(20121208164420, ["/home/richard/recipe/db/migrate"])...assume? am i guessing this is the wrong assumption?

Comment: now i dropped db, re created, deleted schema, new db migrate, schema re generated but still when i create a model no migration file being generated

Comment: Timestamp does not affect migrations. Rails knows what migrations have been done and what migrations haven't by using the schema_versions table. Even schema.rb is not essential to run a Rails application. rake db:reset recreate your database by using your schema.rb. If you want to recreate your database by using your migrations, you should do a rake db:drop db:create db:migrate.

Comment: Rails says "assume_migrated_upto_version" because it uses your schema.rb version (rake db:reset)

Comment: didnt work, whats strange is that when i then re created the rating model after all this the rating table was identical, ie it didnt create a new one and again no migration file

Comment: Have you already tried to destroy and re-create your model? rails destroy model Rating ratings:integer && rails g model Rating ratings:integer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24726/discussion-between-basgys-and-richlewis)